# Rails Authlogic: Login using Database ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-3.2, authlogic

I'm brand new to rails (3.2) and I'm looking for a way to allow users to login using their Database ID and password. Reading the documentation, Authlogic seems to allow login using a login name or email. Is it possible to somehow extend the gem such to allow a user to authenticate by providing their database ID and password?

Here is my current user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation, :current_login_ip, :email, :failed_login_count, :first_name, :last_login_ip, :last_name, :last_request_at, :login_count, :password_salt,
              :perishable_token, :persistence_token, :single_access_token

acts_as_authentic
end
```

And my current User Session model

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
    if @user_session.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged in."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if UserSession.find
      UserSession.find.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully logged out."
    end

    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

My current setup uses email address authentication.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authlogic allows you to choose the column to use as the login field. See  [the Login::Config module](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/acts_as_authentic/login.rb) (`login_field` option):

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.login_field = :database_id_or_whatever_fits_your_needs
end
```

Comment: Found this just before you posted! But this was the solution so thanks.

Comment: If you need other options dig in the sourcess this is much more efficient (all the options are located in modules sitting in the acts_as_authentic directory).